# Data from text file

Tags: powershell

I have text file toto.txt with this content:

```
     Time: 11/23/2018 17:03:46
     User: NEON
     Web Site: https://www.seznam.cz
     Top

     Time: 11/23/2018 17:05:10
     User: NEON
     Web Site: www.autojournal.cz%252Fstat-prodava-zabavena-auta-padouchu-budou-levnejsi-nez-jine-ojetiny-2%252F/keFrdPDIZzLJBC2fxX7EIQ?utm_source=www.seznam.cz&amp;utm_medium=sekce-z-internetu
      Top

 Time: 11/23/2018 17:05:11
 User: NEON
 Web Site: www.autojournal.cz/stat-prodava-zabavena-auta-padouchu-budou-levnejsi-nez-jine-ojetiny-2/?utm_source=www.seznam.cz&amp;utm_medium=sekce-z-internetu
  Top
 ... etc. ...
```

Code for export data:

```
 ((Get-Content C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\toto.txt -RAW) -split '\n(?=Time:)') | % {
     $x = $_ -split '\r'
     New-Object PSOBJECT -Property @{
         Time  = [regex]::Match($x[0],'(?<=Time:\s*)\b.*\b')
         User = [regex]::Match($x[1],'(?<=User:\s*)\b.*\b')
         Web = [regex]::Match($x[2],'(?<=Site:\s*)\b.*\b')
     }
 } | out-file  C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\result.txt
```

The problem is that long urls (web sites) isn´t in result.txt.

And I need structure of result.txt:

datetime;$url for example: 2019-01-15
 15:06:03;$www.autojournal.cz/stat-prodava-zabavena-auta-padouchu-budou-levnejsi-nez-jine-ojetiny-2/?utm_source=www.seznam.cz&utm_medium=sekce-z-internetu

And in result.txt I get: 11/23/2018 17:05:10 NEON
 www.autojournal.cz%252Fstat-prodava-zabavena-auta-padouchu-budou-levnejsi-nez-jine-ojetiny-2%25...

The datetime I can convert with:

```
 (Get-Content C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\result.txt) | 
 Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)", '$3-$1-$2'} | 
 Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "([0-9]+):+([0-9]+):+([0-9]+)", '$1-$2-$3;$'} |
 Set-Content C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\result2.txt


((Get-Content C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\toto.txt -RAW) -split'\n(?=Time:)') | % {
 $x = $_ -split '\r'
 New-Object PSOBJECT -Property @{
     Time  = [regex]::Match($x[0],'(?<=Time:\s*)\b.*\b')
     User = [regex]::Match($x[1],'(?<=User:\s*)\b.*\b')
     Web = [regex]::Match($x[2],'(?<=Site:\s*)\b.*\b')
 } } | out-file  C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\result.txt

 (Get-Content C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\result.txt) |  Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)", '$3-$1-$2'} | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "([0-9]+):+([0-9]+):+([0-9]+)", '$1-$2-$3;$'} | Set-Content C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\result2.txt
```

Comment: [1] PLEASE fix your code formatting. [2] why are you sending your objects out via `| out-file`? you should be using `Export-CSV` since it understands most custom objects & `Out-File` DOES NOT understand custom objects.

Answer (score 0):

Out-File has a "Width" parameter. You can use it to stop it from cutting the line short

```
((Get-Content C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\toto.txt -RAW) -split '\n(?=Time:)') | % {
    $x = $_ -split '\r'
    New-Object PSOBJECT -Property @{
        Time  = [regex]::Match($x[0],'(?<=Time:\s*)\b.*\b')
        User = [regex]::Match($x[1],'(?<=User:\s*)\b.*\b')
        Web = [regex]::Match($x[2],'(?<=Site:\s*)\b.*\b')
    }
} | out-file  C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\result.txt -Width 10000
```

You should also look into working with CSV files with Import-Csv, Export-Csv and [PSCustomObjects] It's way easier than parting txt files.

```
((Get-Content C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\toto.txt -RAW) -split '\n(?=Time:)') | % {
    $x = $_ -split '\r'
    New-Object PSOBJECT -Property @{
        Time  = [regex]::Match($x[0],'(?<=Time:\s*)\b.*\b')
        User = [regex]::Match($x[1],'(?<=User:\s*)\b.*\b')
        Web = [regex]::Match($x[2],'(?<=Site:\s*)\b.*\b')
    }
} | Export-Csv C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\result.txt -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your advice. But in export-csv i have text in " " and I need only text without "", maybe some parametr can I use, I don´t know. And -Delimiter I need ;$, not only ; How Can i add to -Delimiter?

Comment: Ah. Then you can't use those functions. Import/Export-CSV can have only a single character delimiter and by standard, it put quotes around values

Comment: Yes, I know that -Delimiter has only a single char.